# How to execute a ms access vba module in specific day and time?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to execute a vba module (backup module) at a specific day and time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way - schedule a task using Winsows Scheduler. In task you should start MSACCESS.EXE with full path to your accb file and `/x MyMacro` for starting a macro MyMacro, which should start backup process. For instance:

```
msaccess.exe "c:\MyFolder\MyDatabase.accdb" /x MyMacro
```